# Is Marit Ayin necessary?

Tags: marit-ayin

Marit Ayin means that you may not engage in permitted behavior when it may *appear* to a casual observer to be prohibited behavior.  This would cause him:
(1) to assume it is permitted; or, if he knows it isn't,
(2) think ill of you.

On (1), Rav Moshe Feinstein [Igrot Moshe Orach Ḥayyim 1:96; 4:82] tells us that Marit Ayin does not apply in front of ignorant Jews.  One example among many:  most locusts are kosher, but most Jews don't know that and assume they are insects, hence unkosher.  The practice is *not* to refrain from eating them because of Marit Ayin.  (I was surprised, because I thought we must always assume the average passer-by has the knowledge and IQ of a turnip.)

On (2), the Mishnah says that Jews are supposed to practice דָן אֶת כָּל הָאָדָם לְכַף זְכוּת *dan l'khaf zekhut* [Avot 1:6] -- giving people the benefit of the doubt, judging them favorably [Leviticus 19:15], not thinking ill of them, but rather advising them as needed. [Shevuot 30a]  Maimonides says that if you see someone you don’t know do something that can be interpreted as good or bad, you must assume it's good. [Rambam on Avot 1:6]

Given these two pushbacks, why do we have Marit Ayin at all?  If the passer-by is ignorant,
it's your duty to teach him and his duty to seek that knowledge.  If the passer-by thinks ill of you, it's his problem and Chazal say he shouldn't have, and it is *his* Torah duty to inform you of your "mistake", then you can explain to him why it wasn't a mistake.

Comment: The halacha for the individual isn't determined using the assumption that everyone else will always act according to the halacha.

Comment: (Otherwise, there would be no need for rabbinic decrees.)

Comment: Furthermore, the Rambam implies that for someone you don't know, you're only encouraged to assume the best interpretation of his actions when the two interpretations are relatively equiprobable.  He only obligates assuming the otherwise unlikely explanation when that matches better what you already know of the person. Who's to say those who see you know enough about you or about the law to assume the best of you even if they were strict about this principle?